# Defining a :class_name with a string or a symbol in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, associations, symbols

If I have a `Invitation` model and a `User` model, with the `Invitation` model having a `requester_id` column, why does this work,

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :requester, :class_name => "User"
end
```

and this doesn't work?

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :requester, :class_name => :user
end
```

In general, when do I use symbols, and when do I use strings in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2):

#### Either One

You would certainly need `:User`, not `:user.`

The core Ruby [`Symbol`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Symbol.html) defines a [`#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Symbol.html#M000383) and [`String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html) defines a [`#to_sym,`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000783) so in any Ruby context you may often substitute one for another.

I might be tempted to say: when in doubt, [follow the Rails3 API documentation.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)  except it doesn't say, although the example uses a string.  But in this case, it works, you can safely use a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that it is case sensitive. So `:User` *may* work. In any case, I would use a string as that's what it says in the docs :)